# Python splitting data record

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

I have a record as below:

> 29 16
>
> A 1.2595034 0.82587254 0.7375044 1.1270138 -0.35065323 0.55985355
>   0.7200067 -0.889543 0.2300735 0.56767654 0.2789483 0.32296127 -0.6423197 0.26456305 -0.07363393 -1.0788593
>
> B 1.2467299 0.78651106 0.4702038 1.204216 -0.5282698 0.13987103
>   0.5911153 -0.6729466 0.377103 0.34090135 0.3052503 0.028784657 -0.39129165 0.079238065 -0.29310825 -0.99383247

I want to split the data into key-value pairs neglecting the first top row i.e 29 16. It should be neglected.

The output should be something like this:
x = A , B

```
y = 1.2595034 0.82587254 0.7375044 1.1270138 -0.35065323 0.55985355 0.7200067 -0.889543 0.2300735 0.56767654 0.2789483 0.32296127 -0.6423197 0.26456305 -0.07363393 -1.0788593

1.2467299 0.78651106 0.4702038 1.204216 -0.5282698 0.13987103 0.5911153 -0.6729466 0.377103 0.34090135 0.3052503 0.028784657 -0.39129165 0.079238065 -0.29310825 -0.99383247
```

I am able to neglect the first line using the below code:

```
f = open(fileName, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()[1:]
```

Now how do I separate rest record in Python?

Comment: Just be clear, you would like to have something like: `x = '1.259...'` (the string following `A`) and `y = '1.246...` (the string following `B`), or there is more to it?

Comment: No, I need x = A, B in one list

Comment: So, something like `x = ('1.259...', '1.246...')` ?

Comment: And y = 1.259...... 1.246 in another list

Comment: @norok2, yes like x = ('1.259...', '1.246...')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's my take :D I expect you'd want to have the numbers parsed as well?

```
def generate_kv(fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as file:
        # ignore first line
        file.readline()
        for line in file:
            if '' == line.strip():
                # empty line
                continue
            values = line.split(' ')
            try:
                yield values[0], [float(x) for x in values[1:]]
            except ValueError:
                print(f'one of the elements was not a float: {line}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = []
    y = []
    for key, value in generate_kv('sample.txt'):
        x.append(key)
        y.append(value)
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

assumes that the values in sample.txt look like this:

```
% cat sample.txt 
29 16

A 1.2595034 0.82587254 0.7375044 1.1270138 -0.35065323 0.55985355 0.7200067 -0.889543 0.2300735 0.56767654 0.2789483 0.32296127 -0.6423197 0.26456305 -0.07363393 -1.0788593

B 1.2467299 0.78651106 0.4702038 1.204216 -0.5282698 0.13987103 0.5911153 -0.6729466 0.377103 0.34090135 0.3052503 0.028784657 -0.39129165 0.079238065 -0.29310825 -0.99383247
```

and the output:

```
% python sample.py
['A', 'B']
[[1.2595034, 0.82587254, 0.7375044, 1.1270138, -0.35065323, 0.55985355, 0.7200067, -0.889543, 0.2300735, 0.56767654, 0.2789483, 0.32296127, -0.6423197, 0.26456305, -0.07363393, -1.0788593], [1.2467299, 0.78651106, 0.4702038, 1.204216, -0.5282698, 0.13987103, 0.5911153, -0.6729466, 0.377103, 0.34090135, 0.3052503, 0.028784657, -0.39129165, 0.079238065, -0.29310825, -0.99383247]]
```

Alternatively, if you'd wanted to have a dictionary, do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(dict(generate_kv('sample.txt')))
```

That will convert the list into a dictionary and output:

```
{'A': [1.2595034, 0.82587254, 0.7375044, 1.1270138, -0.35065323, 0.55985355, 0.7200067, -0.889543, 0.2300735, 0.56767654, 0.2789483, 0.32296127, -0.6423197, 0.26456305, -0.07363393, -1.0788593], 'B': [1.2467299, 0.78651106, 0.4702038, 1.204216, -0.5282698, 0.13987103, 0.5911153, -0.6729466, 0.377103, 0.34090135, 0.3052503, 0.028784657, -0.39129165, 0.079238065, -0.29310825, -0.99383247]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to store the data in a dictionary here is what you can do:

```
records = dict()
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    f.readline() # skip the first line
    for line in file:
        key, value = line.split(maxsplit=1)
        records[key] = value.split()
```

The structure of `records` would be:

```
{
    'A': ['1.2595034', '0.82587254', '0.7375044', ... ]
    'B': ['1.2467299', '0.78651106', '0.4702038', ... ]
}
```

---

#### What's happening

- `with ... as f` we're opening the file within a *context manager* ([more info here](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/)). This allows us to automatically close the file when the block finishes.
- Because the open file keeps track of where it is in the file we can use `f.readline()` to move the pointer down a line. ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline))
- `line.split()` allows you to turn a string into a list of strings. With the `maxsplits=1` arg it means that it will only split on the first space. 
  e.g. `x, y = 'foo bar baz'.split(maxsplit=1)`, `x = 'foo'` and `y = 'bar baz'`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this script if your file is a text

```
filename='file.text'
with open(filename) as f:
      data = f.readlines()
x=[data[0][0],data[1][0]]
y=[data[0][1:],data[1][1:]]
```

Comment: you can use a pair if you don't like a list x=(data[0][0],data[1][0])
y=(data[0][1:],data[1][1:])

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want the numbers to be collected in a list. One way of doing this is:

```
import string

text = '''
29 16

A 1.2595034 0.82587254 0.7375044 1.1270138 -0.35065323 0.55985355 0.7200067 -0.889543 0.2300735 0.56767654 0.2789483 0.32296127 -0.6423197 0.26456305 -0.07363393 -1.0788593

B 1.2467299 0.78651106 0.4702038 1.204216 -0.5282698 0.13987103 0.5911153 -0.6729466 0.377103 0.34090135 0.3052503 0.028784657 -0.39129165 0.079238065 -0.29310825 -0.99383247
'''

lines = text.split('\n')
x = [
    line[1:].strip().split()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines)
    if line and line[0].lower() in string.ascii_letters]
```

This will produce a list of lists when the outer list contains `A`, `B`, etc. and the inner lists contain the numbers associated to `A`, `B`, etc.

This code assumes that you are interested in lines starting with any single letter (case-insensitive).
For more elaborated conditions you may want to look into [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html).

Obviously, if your `text` is in a file, you could substitute `lines = ...` with:

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as lines:
    x = ...
```

Also, if the items in `x` should not be separated, but rather in a string, you may want to change `line[1:].strip().split()` with `line[1:].strip()`.

Instead, if you want the numbers as `float` and not string, you should replace `line[1:].strip().split()` with `[float(value) for value in line[1:].strip().split()]`.

## EDIT:

Alternatively to `line[1:].strip().split()` you may want to do:

```
line.split(maxsplit=1)[1].split()
```

as suggested in some other answer. This would generalize better if the first token is not a single character.